# RDP over OpenVPN in Windows 8

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, openvpn

I'm trying to configure a Windows 8 computer to allow RDP over OpenVPN. I successfully configured OpenVPN to start at boot, using the OpenVPN service. My problem is that Windows 8 sees the TAP interface as a PUBLIC interface instead of private. So I can't make any changes. Since I'm not familiar with Windows - not familiar at all - could someone supply a step-by-step guide on how to approach this?

I found a couple of answers online on the same topic, but it's not detailed enough for me to handle.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Windows + R -> `gpedit.msc` and go to Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Network List Manager Policies.

When you connect via the TAP, it connects to a network which is probably given a name like "Network 3" or similar.  Clicking on the network icon in the system tray ought to show that, or you can go to Network and Sharing Center.

[image]

Comment: Can't find `gpedit.msc` which means that I have Windows 8.1 an alternate edition. I think I'll go with Teamviewer. I'll probably pay for a license. Thanks.